# Is it possible to launch one of my custom AWS AMI using CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

Basically, what I am looking for is the CLI version of http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/launching-instance.html

Previously I have saved my instance as EBS AMI, and want to launch it using command line preferably, or APIs, instead of using Web Interface.

Thank you.

Comment: This sort of question is too broad for SO.  The CLI you're looking for is here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html If you have any specific issues with it, please edit this question to include what you've tried and the specific problem you're encountering.

Comment: Can you be more specific? It is certainly possible, and trivially findable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of launching a new Amazon EC2 instance via the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) with a specified Amazon Machine Image (AMI):

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-abcd1234 --security-group-id sg-abcd1234 --instance-type t1.micro
```

See: [AWS CLI `run-instances` documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html)